# How to distribute multiple HBoxes equally in length so that they have equal spans from one side of a scene to the other

Tags: javafx

I have HBoxes nested in one HBox that spans from one side of the window to another. What I want is the length of those four HBoxes to be distributed equally so that they have the same span whenever the window is resized!

My code snippet:

```
<HBox prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0">
               <children>
                  <HBox>
                     <children>
                        <Pane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: #abb7b7;" />
                     </children>
                     <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
                     </padding>
                  </HBox>
                  <HBox>
                     <children>
                        <Pane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: #6c7a89;" />
                     </children>
                     <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
                     </padding>
                  </HBox>
                  <HBox>
                     <children>
                        <Pane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: #008080;" />
                     </children>
                     <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
                     </padding>
                  </HBox>
               </children>
            </HBox>
```

Comment: I do not know the answer, but have you tried working with this structure: HBox > AnchorPane > HBox, you can pin objects in AnchorPanes.. Maybe this will help. I hate the layouting in JFX ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `hgrow` property on each of the 'child' `HBox`es:

```
<HBox prefHeight="150" prefWidth="200">

    <HBox HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
        <!-- ... -->
    </HBox>

   <HBox HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
        <!-- ... -->
    </HBox>

    <!-- ... -->

</HBox>
```